# Summing 1 to even integer doubles the result

Tags: python

I was trying to come up with a simple on-liner to detect if an integer was even and if not add 1 to make it even. So I came up with this:

```
N = 62465
N += 1 if bool(N % 2) else N
print N
```

This works fine if `N` is odd but if it is even it returns *double* the value. What is happening here?

Comment: Order of operations works like this: `N += (1 if bool(N % 2) else N)`.

Comment: You need `else 0` not `else N`. Or just: `N += N % 2`

Comment: Ohh I see where my mistake is now. Thanks guys, would anyone mind posting a comment as a result so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Two downvotes and no explanation why? Nice. Apparently you can't let anything get past you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *doubling* your `N` when it is even; you essentially do this:

```
if N % 2:
    N += 1
else:
    N += N
```

You'd want to use `N += 1 if N % 2 else 0` instead (the `bool()` is implied in conditionals).

To simplify that you can just add `N % 2` as that'll be `0` for even and `1` for odd:

```
N += N % 2
```

Comment: (I'm sure I made this comment here before. Odd that I can't find it anymore) I like the way you propose very much, simple and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The often-used way of doing this is by dividing then multiplying.

```
N = (N + 2 - 1)//2*2
```

This works with other moduluses that are not 2.